# Is there any way to make Python .format() thow an exception if the data won't fit the field?

Tags: python, format

I want to normalize floating-point numbers to nn.nn strings, and to do some special handling if the number is out of range.

```
try:
    norm = '{:5.2f}'.format(f)
except ValueError:
    norm = 'BadData' # actually a bit more complex than this
```

except it doesn't work: `.format` silently overflows the 5-character width. Obviously I could length-check `norm` and raise my own ValueError, but have I missed any way to force format (or the older `%` formatting) to raise an exception on field-width overflow?

Comment: Can you be more clear by giving the sample example?

Comment: Er, what? `'{:5.2f}'.format(12.0)` returns `12.00`, but `'{:5.2f}'.format(1001.0)` returns `1001.00` which is more than the requested five characters long. I'd like an exception to be raised if the data won't fit in five characters with two decimal places.

Comment: I guess you have to check if yourself: `math.log10(value) >= 3.0` would the the mathematical way. Check the length of the string the lazy one.

Comment: Check the length of the string is the *right* way if the data is headed for a char(5) database field (which it is, and no, I cannot change the database schema!). Also `log10` will blow up on negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this with `format()`. You have to create your custom formatter which raises the exception. For example:

```
def format_float(num, max_int=5, decimal=2):
    if len(str(num).split('.')[0])>max_int:
         raise ValueError('Integer part of float can have maximum {} digits'.format(max_int))
    return "{:.2f}".format(num)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> format_float(123.456)
'123.46'

>>> format_float(123.4)
'123.40'

>>> format_float(123789.456)  # Error since integer part is having length more than 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in format_float
ValueError: Integer part of float can have maximum 5 digits
```